# Static Method PHP-OOP

Tags: php, oop

I want to access Static method properties to other static method. I am trying to access it via:

```
public static function getGender($user) {   
    $user_data[] = Common::getSomeUsers(true);
    $ssn_to_gender[] = array();
    foreach($user_data as $u_data){
        foreach($u_data as $key => $user){
            '$key:' .$user['ssn'];
            $ssn = $user['ssn'] . "<br/>";
            //echo $ssn;
            $ssn_gender= substr($ssn,7,-6) . "<br/>" ;
            $dob_gender= substr($ssn,0,6) . "<br/>" ;
            echo $dob_gender;
            if($ssn_gender % 2 == 0 )
            {
                echo 'F' . '</br>';
                $ssn_to_gender[$user['ssn']] = 'F';
            }
            elseif($ssn_gender % 2 == 1)
            {
                echo 'M' .'<br/>';
                $ssn_to_gender[$user['ssn']] = 'M';
            }

        }

    }
    return $ssn_to_gender;
    return $dob_gender;
    //$user= array();
    //echo Common::getSomeUsers($user);

}

public static function getAge( $user ) {


    self::getGender(true);
    Common::$dob_gender;

}
Common::getAge($userid='');
echo Common::$dob_gender;
```

I am trying to access `$dob_gender` variable in `get_Age()` method from `getGender()` method.

But unable to get the `$dob_gender`. Please guide I am new with PHP and object oriented programming.

Thanks.

Comment: Are these static functions actually inside a class?

Comment: You have to return an array at the end: `return $ssn_to_gender; return $dob_gender;` so `return ['ssn'=>$ssn_to_gender,'dob'=>
    $dob_gender];` or similar. As soon as you return the first value, that script portion is done. It won't return the second value because it's already returned the first.

Comment: I don't see a declaration of `$dob_gender` in the code.

Comment: As noted you need to declare the variable as static, then assign it using `self` so `self::$dob_gender`

Comment: I think you should try making these just plain ol' functions for now until you get a better handle on PHP. There seems to be no rhyme nor reason for why you are making these methods and variables static.

Comment: @JonStirling yes these are inside the class.

Comment: @Rasclatt i will try this and update.. thanks

Comment: @AniketSahrawat yes it has been declared like this inside the class:  static public $dob_gender;
static public $ssn_to_gender;

Comment: @Rasclatt thanks man it worked for me :) the array thing helped me.

Comment: I would look at not making it static as I described in my answer. You want to limit static methods as much as possible.

Comment: @Rasclatt yes i will do that. But there is some requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would think about doing a standard method instead of a series of static methods:

```
class Common
{
    private   $ssn_to_gender,
              $dob_gender;
    /**
    *  @returns  Itself (Common object)
    */
    public function getGender($user)
    {
        $user_data[]           =  $this->getSomeUsers(true);
        $this->ssn_to_gender[] =  array();

        foreach($user_data as $u_data){
            foreach($u_data as $key => $user){
                $ssn              =  $user['ssn'];
                $ssn_gender       =  substr($ssn,7,-6);
                $this->dob_gender = substr($ssn,0,6);

                if($ssn_gender % 2 == 0 ) {
                    $this->ssn_to_gender[$user['ssn']] = 'F';
                }
                elseif($ssn_gender % 2 == 1) {
                    $this->ssn_to_gender[$user['ssn']] = 'M';
                }
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }
    /**
    *  @returns  The corresponding private variable
    */
    public function getSSNToGender()
    {
        return $this->ssn_to_gender;
    }
    /**
    *  @returns  The corresponding private variable
    */
    public function getDOBGender()
    {
        return $this->dob_gender;
    }
    /**
    *  @question   I am not sure the purpose of this method. Presumably you need to
    *              do more in the way of script otherwise you would just do the
    *              getGender() method instead
    */
    public function getAge($userid)
    {
        # I am returning this but presumably you want to do something else??
        return $this->getGender($userid);
    }
}
```

To use would be like:

```
$Common = new Common();
$Age    = $Common->getAge($userid);

print_r($Age->getDOBGender());
print_r($Age->getSSNToGender());
```